# Pass date as a parameter into report

Tags: c#, parameters, datetimepicker, report-designer

I am working on creating an application that calculates the net weight, on one of the forms i have to provide the user with the option of choosing an item from the drop down combo box and also give the user an option of choosing any date from the date time picker and i have to place that as a parameter in the text box on my report, i didn't have any problem populating the combobox for choosing an item because those items are in the database table, i used the sql command got the column then passed that as a parameter to fill the drop down and then set the same but date time picker the user can select any date they wish how would one pass that value on to the report for a visual of what i am talking about click [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQCHa.png) I created my report using the GUI and the gui generated this code that loads the report with the one parameter that i am setting.

```
private void PieceCodepc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    reportViewer1.Visible = false;
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.DataTable1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.DataTable1);

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tableforReport.CandyPieceSize' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.CandyPieceSizeTableAdapter.Fill(this.tableforReport.CandyPieceSize);
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'empty.Piece_Dimension_Master_Data' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.Piece_Dimension_Master_DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.empty.Piece_Dimension_Master_Data, comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working wanted to post it as an answer so others can benefit from similar situations.

```
 private void setFiltersParameters()
        {
            this.Piece_Dimension_Master_DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.empty.Piece_Dimension_Master_Data, comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
            ReportParameter date = new ReportParameter("date", dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString());
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { date });
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

When the button is clicked i call the above method as such

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setFiltersParameters();
            reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
            button1.PerformClick();
            reportViewer1.Visible = true;
        }
```